# switch-case automatic break

Tags: c, switch-statement

Are there any C compilers with extensions that provide the ability to automatically break at the end of each case statement (similar to what Swift has available) or an alterate switch available in a future C spec?

Mostly interested in this to avoid clutter in extensive switch-case scenarios.

I find this works "ok" but would prefer something clearer about the behavior.

```
#define case   break; { } case
#define switch_break switch

switch_break (action) 
{
    default: printf ("Unknown action");

    case action_none   :   // Nothing
    case action_copy   :   doCopy ();
    case action_paste  :   doPaste ();         
    case action_none   :   break;  /* C requires a statement after final case */

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. It might cause a lot of confusion for anyone who didn't catch your `define` macros.

Comment: Code is mostly for reading by other humans? You just decided that in your book sentences will end with a question mark? This causes others who read it to context switch between normal reading and your special reading? Isn't that annoying.

Comment: Recommended reading: [A rant against flow control macros](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/06/347666.aspx). Key point: *When you create a flow-control macro, you're modifying the language. When I fire up an editor on a file whose name ends in ".cpp" I expect that what I see will be C++ and not some strange dialect that strongly resembles C++ except in the places where it doesn't.*

Comment: Any such compiler would not be a C compiler, and so probably of limited use.

Comment: Techniques like [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) would stop working if a future C spec changed the meaning of the `switch` statement.

Comment: There are often times when one doesn't *want* a break after every case (not just Duff's device... also any time when more than one value needs the same code).

Comment: @Dmitri: arguably, it happens way more often to want to break at every case, and when you need to exploit the fallthrough feature you'll comment it anyway to remark that it's not an error (unless there are several cases that share the same whole block). The problem is not that the current state of the language is better than the proposed alternative (it's not), but that using macros/custom extensions to deeply change the semantic of core language features is a serious problem for anyone else who'll have to read your code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia To some extent, it's a matter of preference and style.  I've run into many situations when using other languages where fallthrough would've been really convenient, but wasn't an option because that language's switch analog didn't allow it.  Also, C's switch doesn't allow one statement block for several values except via fallthrough.

Comment: To avoid confusion I'd do `#define CASE_BREAK   break; case` and then use `CASE_BREAK` instead of `case`, where you need this "extension".

Comment: @Dmitri: I too missed the fallthrough in other languages, my point is that it's not the common situation, so maybe a better idea would have been to require a keywork for the fallthrough, not for the common `break` case (although it's easy to see how the current syntax stems from the original status of C as a higher-level assembly).

Comment: @legends2k -- I'd hate anything that wasn't proper C, but in the "prototype" I used "switch_break" instead of switch to at least mark the idea of altered behavior.

I wish in C15 or whatever the next spec is, they make some differently named variant of "switch" with this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you hate writing `break` everytime, wrap the `switch` statement inside a function. Then `break` can be replaced with `return` statements. For example

```
int switch_func(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'a': return 1;
        case 'b': return 3;
        case 'c': return 5;
        case 'd': return 7;
        . . .
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Reduces code only if return values are present.

Comment: Of course you can do that, but then you are needlessly nesting away the code for no particular reason.  If you have a flow of events, it usually isn't helpful to hide away some code without some valid reason.   Especially if only a single function would ever use it, it isn't optimal design.

Comment: @B.Nadolson and you want to avoid writing `break` without any valid reason.

Comment: Less typing of redundancy where possible is important to me.